# Unity UI seems to be showing old (cached maybe) values

Tags: c#, user-interface, unity-game-engine

I have a UIPanel Prefab (ItemDetailedView GameObject) that has its own script (ItemDetailedView.cs)

I instantiate the ItemDetailedView GameObject and then get its component script and tell it to show the details for an item.

The problem is, the details view always shows the last item I looked at.
Even if the game is stopped and restarted the first item view will be of the last item I looked at the last time the game ran!!

Is there a "Force GUI Update" call I should be making?

```
//This is set to the prefab in the inspector
public GameObject ViewItemPrefab

//called from an inventory view button listener
private void ViewDetails(Item item)
{
     //Shows the correct item.Name
     print("about to show details for " + item.Name);

     //instantiates nicely
     Instantiate(ViewItemPrefab, transform.parent);
     ViewItemPrefab.GetComponent<GUIDetailedItemViewWindow>().Show(item);
}

public class GUIDetailedItemViewWindow : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Item item;

    //text UI object set in the inspector
    public Text ItemNameText;

    public void Show(Item itemToShow)
    {
        //this prints the right Name
        print("itemToShow name: " + itemToShow.Name);

        item = itemToShow;

        //this prints the right Name too!
        print("Item to view details for: " + item.Name);

        //this shows the Name of the last Item we were looking at!
        // this is the problem here!
        // it will even show the name of the item I looked at last time I ran the game!
        ItemNameText.text = item.Name;


        //now it gets really weird
        //this shows the correct item name!
        print("ItemNameText.text is " + ItemNameText.text);

    }
}
```

Next time I try to view the details of an item it will show the last item we tried to view the details for.

I am absolutely confounded.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line

```
ViewItemPrefab.GetComponent<GUIDetailedItemViewWindow>().Show(item);
```

gets the component of the *prefab*, not the newly instantiated object.

This is why you see the values the next time you create a window, and also why it persists over game resets (only the scene is restored, but you modified a prefab). To access the new object do something to the effect of

```
GameObject details = Instantiate(ViewItemPrefab, transform.parent);
details.GetComponent<GUIDetailedItemViewWindow>().Show(item);
```

Comment: Yes!! Fixed. Thanks!!